# How to upload image using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, image-uploading

How can I send an image on my server using AJAX to a remote PHP server which is also mine? I don't know how to send and how to save using PHP. I tried to put the image in an iframe and send its content using AJAX like below but nothing happened as you might guess... It returns a message that show it is receiving some stuff and creates a very small broken image.

```
...
var url = "www.xyz.com/AJAX.php?content=" + document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a good example you could use [Ajax Image Uploading](http://css-tricks.com/ajax-image-uploading/)

Comment: These plugins read data from file input fields, I don't have it in my case. How can I do it automatically? My idea was to attach the image to document, read it using js and send using ajax. Seems very odd in deed...

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at jQuery yet? Its really easy doing ajax calls with it.

For your Image Uploading you might wanna have a look at jquery Forms, it has some sample codes in it here : http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

Comment: I know jQuery but I sometimes like old ways :)